# How to use an instance variable twice without renaming it?

Tags: java

Help, I just started learning Java, and this online tutorial I am doing is asking me to create an instance that belongs to a class. This instance is supposed to be created as a "Rectangle" object first, then later as a "Circle" object. But Eclipse is asking me to rename the second "drawObject".

```
public class TestPolymorph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
        drawObject.draw();

        Shape drawObject = new Circle(40);
        drawObject.draw();

    }
}
```

Comment: This should work if `Rectangle` and `Circle` both extends/implements `Shape`. Do they?

Comment: @Sweeper It won't work because OP is declaring 2 variables in the same scope with the same name.

Comment: You can also remove the word `Shape` in the circle creation line. (You can't have two _declarations_ of an identifier with the same name in the same scope, but the second can be an assignment. The tutorial's instructions seems a little off....it's not the same "instance." There are two different instances here.

Comment: Yes, both classes implements the Shape class. In the Shape class, the only method is an abstract method as below.

public interface Shape {
 
 public abstract void draw();
}

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Oh! How did I miss that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You recalled Shape again, here would be the appropriate fix

Edited to give him a better solution

```
public class TestPolymorph {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
        drawObject.draw();

        drawObject = new Circle(40);
        drawObject.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dukeling he recalled drawObject again when it should be a fundamental java logic error

Comment: Although this tutorial *might* cover this question, it does not help to just link to the tutorial as a whole. Please extract the section, that discusses this specific topic.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to post some guidence link use comment

Comment: Please refer to the new answer for a better explanation

Comment: "_You recalled Shape again_" it is called a declaration.

Comment: @AxelH well hes not supposed to call the same declaration right

Comment: But you are not using the correct terminology so your answer don't make sense.

Answer (score 12):

You are declaring the variable twice. Instead, override it by removing the type declaration at the second instantiation:

```
public class TestPolymorph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
        drawObject.draw();

        drawObject = new Circle(40);
        drawObject.draw();

    }
}
```

I do encourage you to change the name to a value that makes more sense though:

```
public class TestPolymorph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape rectangleShape = new Rectangle(40,60);
        rectangleShape.draw();

        Shape circleShape = new Circle(40);
        circleShape.draw();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define it without creating new object:

```
    Shape drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
    drawObject.draw();

    drawObject = new Circle(40);
    drawObject.draw();
```

After this code, drawObject references a Circle type object.

Answer (score 1):

Once you define the datatype for an Object if you want to re use the variable you should simply assign the new value to the variable (without using the data type). In your case:

```
int i = 0;
int i = 1; \\it won't work. because you already define the datatype
```

Instead:

```
int i = 0;
i = 1; \\This will work. you don't have to define the datatype again for the same variable
```

Use `drawObject = new Circle(40);` for second time

Comment: "_because you already define the datatype_" not really, it is not a problem of "_datatype_". You can't have `long i` either. The reason is you can't declare two variables in the same scope with a same name.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class TestPolymorph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
        drawObject.draw();

        drawObject = new Circle(40);
        drawObject.draw();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I go with Randy,
you have to visualize the the relations between your Objects.
Rectangle and Circle inhert from Shape. So both, Circle and Rect, can be a Shape. Because of that it is possible to change
 your drawObject from Rectangle to a Circle but the declaration of multiple variables with the same name is wrong.
Your Object drawObject in general is just a pointer on thr Stack pointing to an Object ( Rectangle or Circle) on the Heap. This variable always have to be unique so you can change the Object they are referencing but never have the same Variable twice

Answer (score 1):

You can not use same name for two variables within same scope. 
If Rectangle and Circle you extends Shape then you this will work.

```
public class TestPolymorph {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
        drawObject.draw();

        drawObject = new Circle(40);
        drawObject.draw();

    }
}
```

notice that I have remove Type declaration when I am assigning the same reference variable the second time i.e  reference of New circle to the reference variable drawObject.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign an instance of a class to a reference of a class which either extends it or is of the same type. If not it wont allow you to do the same. In this case Circle and Rectangle should extend/implement Shape.

Comment: True but that's not the point of the problem. You can declare twice a variable with same names.

Comment: You can only declare variables with same name under different scopes. It is not valid to declare same named variable twice in the same scope. You better can reuse the previous variable.

Comment: But that's not what you said in your answer... you only point the possible problem of inheritence. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not about eclipse, java does not allows duplicate names in the same scope. Since you have both lines in same block `{}` here its `main()`, hence you have error pointed out by your IDE.

How to resolve?

Option 1: Use different blocks

```
{
   Shape drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
   drawObject.draw();
}

{
   Shape drawObject = new Circle(40);
   drawObject.draw();
}
```

Option 2: Use same variable.

```
   Shape drawObject;
   drawObject = new Rectangle(40,60);
   drawObject.draw();
   drawObject = new Circle(40);
   drawObject.draw();
```

Option 3: Use different variable names